# Breaking probability theory by having a different number of random variables depending on a conditioning random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I suspect I'm breaking probability theory but I don't know how or why.
How does one handle working with conditional probabilities where one can have a different number of random variables depending on the conditioning random variable? I haven't come across any literature regarding such a case explicitly.

For example:

$ f(a) = p(a | X)  , X \in \{1,2\}\!$

and $ a $ is some set of random variables (depending on the value of $X$).

where for example we have a pdf
$ p( b,c | X = 1)  \!$

and
$ p( d,e,f | X = 2) \! $

Would this even make sense to work with in this form?

What is marginalizing out X:

$\int dX p(a | X) p(X) $ in such a situation?

Lets say $ p(X=1) = 0.5 \!$
and a is a normal pdf with varying dimentionality.

$ p(b,c | X =1) \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{bc}, \Sigma_{bc}) $

$ p(d,e,f | X=2) \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{def}, \Sigma_{def}) $

$ \sum_X p(a | X) p(X)\! $ doesn't even make sense but I don't understand how I'm breaking probability theory. How can you sum two weighted Gaussian pdfs of different dimentionality? (If they had the same RVs one could easily handle such a case)

This wouldn't even make sense even if $b,c,d,e$ were all discrete.

Something similar is done in Bayesian probability theory for the Bayes factor where one can have different numbers of parameters but this doesn't violate the rules or one's intuition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor

$ K = \frac{\Pr(D|M_1)}{\Pr(D|M_2)}
= \frac{\int \Pr(\theta_1|M_1)\Pr(D|\theta_1,M_1)\,d\theta_1}
{\int \Pr(\theta_2|M_2)\Pr(D|\theta_2,M_2)\,d\theta_2} .\!$

I must admit that conditional probabilities have always been a little mysterious to me.

**Edit: Thinking about what you are saying Sam Jaques.**

Here is an example
I think one can write the probabilities as follows.
$ p(a | X) = \begin{Bmatrix}
  p(\text{"a is b,c"},b,c | X=1)  \\
  p(\text{"a is d,e,f"},d,e,f | X=2) 
 \end{Bmatrix}  $

$ p(b,c) \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{bc}, \Sigma_{bc}) $

$ p(d,e,f) \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu_{def}, \Sigma_{def}) $

$ p(X) =  \begin{Bmatrix}
  0.5,  X=1  \\
  0.5, X=2 
 \end{Bmatrix}  $

Now would $ p(a | X)p(X) $ make sense?

$ p(a | X) = \begin{Bmatrix}
  p(\text{"a is b,c"},b,c | X=1) \times p(X = 1) \\
  p(\text{"a is d,e,f"},d,e,f | X=2) \times p(X = 2)
 \end{Bmatrix}  $

$ p(a | X) = \begin{Bmatrix}
  p(\text{"a is b,c"},b,c | X=1) \times 0.5 \\
  p(\text{"a is d,e,f"},d,e,f | X=2) \times 0.5
 \end{Bmatrix} $

Which is still pretty weird but kindof makes sense.

Now for the crux

$ \sum_X p(a |X)p(X) = p(a) $

$ p(a) = p(\text{"a is b,c"},b,c | X=1) \times 0.5 + p(\text{"a is d,e,f"},d,e,f | X=2) \times 0.5 $

Now using what you said:

$ p(a) = p(b,c) \times 0.5 + p(d,e,f) \times 0.5 $

Is this a valid pdf? It integrates to 1.
But writing out our proposition $a$ is what?

$ p(a) = p(\text{"a is b,c or d,e,f"},b,c,d,e,f)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a devout Bayesian and my approach to probability theory may be a bit non-standard.

Probabilities match propositions to numbers. So what you're asking with $p(b=x,c=y|X=1)$ is "What's the probability that b=x and c=y, given that $X=1$?" When you have a pdf, you're just looking at all possible values for $b$ and $c$, and considering that set of probabilities.

When you have a probability, say $P(A|B)$, both $A$ and $B$ are propositions. For notational convenience, if there's a distribution along a random variable X, we can use propositions like "X=x" for some x in some set S, and ask for $P(X=x|B)$. Then $p(X|B)$, as a probability distribution, refers to the set of probabilities $\{P(X=x|B)|x\in S\}$.  In this case, "X" stands in for a set of propositions on some random variable.

When you say that $a$ is a different number of variables depending on $X$, you could consider this as the set of probabilities: $$\{P(\text{''a is b and c"}, b=s, c=r|X=x)|s\in B,r\in C,x\in\{0,1\}\}\cup\{P(\text{''a is d,e, and f"},d=s,e=r,f=t|X=x)|s\in D,r\in E,t\in F,x\in\{0,1\}\}$$ When you "marginalize out" $X$, you still get a valid probability distribution, its just that the propositions involved aren't just simple $X=x$ propositions anymore; they include these weird statements asserting what $a$ is.

To actually calculate this, you can use Baye's rule and do: $$P(\text{''a is b and c"},b=s,c=r|X=x)=P(b=r,c=s|\text{''a is b and c"},X=x)P(\text{"a is b and c"}|X=x)$$Since $X$ seems to only control what $a$ is, then the values of $b$ and $c$ are conditionally independent of $X$, so you get:
$$P(\text{''a is b and c"},b=s,c=r|X)=P(b=s,c=r|\text{''a is b and c"})P(\text{"a is b and c"}|X=x)$$
And $P(\text{''a is b and c"}|X=1)=1$ and $P(\text{''a is b and c"}|X=2)=0$. In the example you gave $P(b=x,c=y|\text{''a is b and c"})$ would be given by the normal distribution.

If it still doesn't make sense, try to think of an example where this problem would come up and I'll see if I can work through it.

Comment: Wow, this puts a different perspective on things and is starting to make sense. I'll have to think about this a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I've tried to go one step further if you don't mind taking a look.